# How to write INT64 to CString

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cstring, int64

I am coding in c++ windows.

```
INT64 dirID = -1;
CString querySQLStr = _T("");
querySQLStr.Format(L"select * from ImageInfo where FolderPath=%64d;", dirID);

querySQLStr always like this:
select * from ImageInfo where FolderPath=                                                            1214;
```

is it right to use %64d？
Many Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a windows machine handy to test this on, but I think CString should accept this:

```
querySQLStr.Format("%I64d", dirID);
```

It's probably worth noting that this is windows specific, but since you're using CString I guess that's okay.

Comment: I can confirm it does work. %lld (two lowercase Ls) will also work, the 'll' referring to LONGLONG, which (under Win32 at least) is typedefed as _int64, as is INT64 (defined by different header files).

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try this:

```
__int64 val;
......
ParamVal.Format( _T("%d{I64}"), val);
```

Answer (score 0):

**%lld** and **%I64d** both work equally as well.

```
strCode.Format(_T("Code = %lld, Result = %I64d \n"),lCode,lResult);
```